# MongoDB: returning dynamic field from the result

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

Consider a collection,

```
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.col.find({});
{ "_id" : 1, "height" : 150, "weight" : 60 }
```

I want to write a function to dynamically return the field value based on input.

```
function getFieldValue(inputField){
    
    var resultDoc = db.col.findAndModify({
        query:{_id: 1 },
        update: {$inc:{[inputField]:1}},
        new:true
        });
    
    return resultDoc;
}
```

This will return the whole document. How can I return only the field that was passed as input?

```
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> var x = getFieldValue("weight")
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> x
61
```

I tried `resultDoc.[inputField]`, but that causes syntax error.

Comment: you dont need the dot, so `resultDoc[inputField]`

Comment: Thanks, @keja. If you can put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the dot in `resultDoc.[inputField]` so it would be `resultDoc[inputField]`.